# How to position font awesome icon vertically

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using the tont awesome volume icon on a webpage. I'm having difficulty positioning it vertically in its parent p element. This is the html code

```
<p class="dlg_content eng_dlg"><span class="dlg_text" id="bf01">Shopkeeper:     Good afternoon, how can  I help you?</span>&#xa0;<span class ="fa fa-volume-up fa-volume-up-dlg"></span> </p>
```

and this the css

```
span.dlg_text  {
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
span.fa-volume-up-dlg  {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

at the moment the volume icon displays at the top of p.dlg_content. It needs to be aligned to the vertical middle. I've been varying the 
    span.fa-volume-up-dlg properties but I've not been come up with something that works. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
span.dlg_text {
    margin-left: 2%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.fa-volume-up-dlg {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/557/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. The css doesn't work. I can't see why. The jsfiddle obviously works. span.dlg_text and span.fa-volume-up-dlg are only referenced at this place in the css, so it shouldn't be a specificity problem (so far as I understand). I'm puzzled about this

Comment: Share a link where you have implemented this, if possible. Also have a look at the console for errors

Comment: link as requested http://www.english2theworld.com/index.php/courses/dialogs/buying-flowers  I couldn't detect any errors with firebug console.

Comment: Remove "position:absolute" from span.fa-volume-up

Comment: I moved the "position: absolute" to span.fa_volume_ws. this fixed both the alignment in the buying flowers page and the volume-up icon in the word set dialog boxes. Thank very much for your help, it really pointed the way to go. Best regards